# Swift - can not get value of dictionary class extend from class

Tags: swift

Simple problem, but i don't know why!!

- Create an class - A, and class B extend from B.
- Create a collection

  *public var hm : [B : Int] = [:]*

Class A - defined:

```
class A : Hashable {
    var x : Double = 0
    var y : Double = 0
    init(x : Double, y : Double) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }
    var hashValue : Int {
        get {
            // IMPORTANT!!! Do some operations to generate a unique hash.
            return ObjectIdentifier(self).hashValue
        }
    }
    static func == (lhs: A, rhs: A) -> Bool {
        //return ObjectIdentifier(lhs) == ObjectIdentifier(rhs)
        return (lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y)
    }
}

class B : A {

}
```

A function check to get value of collection - hm.

```
     func check(a1 : B, a2 : B){
        print("\na1: \(a1.x)  \(a1.y)")
        if let y1 = hm[a1] {
            print(y1)
        }else{
            print("false a1")
        }

        print("\na2: \(a2.x)  \(a2.y)")
        if let y2 = hm[a2] {
            print(y2)
        }else{
            print("false a2")
        }
    }
```

and, finally create a function test() is main for testing.

```
func test() -> Void {
        let a1 : B = B(x: 9.0, y: 12.0)
        let a2 : B = B(x: 19.0, y: 42.0)


        hm[a1] = 99
        hm[a2] = 20

        let a3 : B = B(x: 9.0, y: 12.0)
        let a4 : B = B(x: 19.0, y: 42.0)

        print("----Content of hm-----")
        for (key, val) in hm {
            print("x: \(key.x)  | y: \(key.y)  | val: = \(val)")
        }

        check(a1: a3, a2: a4)
    }
```

On main thread call test().
Output is:

```
----Content of hm-----
x: 19.0  | y: 42.0  | val: = 20
x: 9.0  | y: 12.0  | val: = 99

a1: 9.0  12.0
99

a2: 19.0  42.0
false a2
```

Why, print "false a2" -> **not found a2 inside of collection** hm?

For compare 2 objects i use: (lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y). 
(if use ObjectIdentifier then result always false for compare)

Thank you for explaining.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it behaves like that exactly, but I can tell what the issue is: you're implementing `Hashable` wrong.

One important condition of conforming to `Hashable` is that "equal objects have the same `hashValue`", which is not true in your case. Once you break this fundamental assumption, all code that depends on it will likely break (like `Dictionary`).

In this example you should either make `A` work on identity (in this case `==` would be the same as `===`), or work on values (in this case `hashValue` would depend only on `x` and `y`).

The important thing to note here is that `Hashable` doesn't just mean "it's a value that can produce a hash of itself", but it's actually a subprotocol of `Equatable`. As such, it really means "An object that can be checked for equality, and can also do a preliminary equality check with a hash value that it can produce".

Answer (score 0):

Delete your implementation of `hashValue` and replace insert this instead:

```
func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    x.hash(into:&hasher)
    y.hash(into:&hasher)
}
```